# Get the total usage (in percent) between two specified dates

Tags: sql-server-2017

I have table at SQL server 2017:

[image: Usage Statistics table]

Number 1 represent the test equipment, it is connecting and 0 is disconnected. 
need your help to define query that can give me the amount of usage (in percentage) to :

- Connect Statistics In accordance with the selected range of DateTime in 
  specific "DeviceName" and "PcName"
- Running Statistics In accordance with the selected range of DateTime 
  in specific "PcName"

Thank you for your help

```
 USE [LabDevices]  
  GO
  INSERT INTO [dbo].[Statistics]
               ([DeviceName]
               ,[ConnectStatistics]
               ,[RunningStatistics]
               ,[DateTime]
               ,[PcName])
         VALUES
               (<DeviceName, varchar(50),>
               ,<ConnectStatistics, bit,>
               ,<RunningStatistics, bit,>
               ,<DateTime, datetime,>
               ,<PcName, varchar(50),>)
  GO
  INSERT INTO [dbo].[Statistics] (DeviceName,ConnectStatistics,RunningStatistics,DateTime,PcName)
    VALUES ('Regatron_1', 1 , 0 , '2019-02-27 08:00:00','PC1'),
           ('Regatron_1', 1 , 1 , '2019-02-27 08:10:00','PC1'),
           ('Regatron_1', 1 , 0 , '2019-02-27 08:50:00','PC1'),
           ('Regatron_1', 1 , 1 , '2019-02-27 09:20:00','PC1'),
           ('Regatron_1', 0 , 0 , '2019-02-27 09:40:00','PC1'),
           ('Regatron_2', 1 , 0 , '2019-02-27 08:00:00','PC2'),
           ('Regatron_2', 1 , 1 , '2019-02-27 08:10:00','PC2'),
           ('Regatron_2', 1 , 0 , '2019-02-27 08:50:00','PC2'),
           ('Regatron_2', 1 , 1 , '2019-02-27 09:20:00','PC2'),
           ('Regatron_2', 0 , 0 , '2019-02-27 09:40:00','PC2')
```

Hi

First thank for your help

Let me clarify the question and expected result:

The query should generate the used time for each device in percent

In case the selected time is between '2019-02-27 08:00:00' to '2019-02-27 09:40:00' -> time range is 1.4

Regatron_1_ConnectStatistics -> from 8:00 to 09:40 = 1.4

Regatron_1_RunningStatistics -> from 08:10 to 08:50 and 09:20 to 09:40 = 1

Regatron_2_ConnectStatistics -> from 8:00 to 09:40 = 1.4

Regatron_2_RunningStatistics -> from 08:10 to 08:50 and 09:20 to 09:40 = 1 The answer:

Regatron_1_ConnectStatistics(%) = (1.4/1.4)*100

Regatron_1_RunningStatistics(%) = (1/1.4)*100

Regatron_2_ConnectStatistics(%) = (1.4/1.4)*100

Regatron_2_RunningStatistics(%) = (1/1.4)*100

Can you help to define the correct query?

Thanks

Comment: Please add the desired result.

Comment: 1) Replace screenshot with textual variant (the best way - with CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO form, or create a fiddle) 2) Show desured output on THAT source data with explaination how it is calculated.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your requirment correctly your command should be like this, if not please provide example result.

```
Select DeviceName, (Count(ConnectStatistics)* 100 / (Select Count(*) From [dbo].[Statistics])) as Score, pcname
From [dbo].[Statistics]
where datetime = '2019-02-27 09:40:00'
Group By DeviceName,pcname
```

[image]